# Trying to make jetty v10 serve two webapps at a single subdomain

Tags: jetty, virtualhost

Using jetty v10 I'm trying to make it respond to 4 requests:-

**mydomain.org** - I set the folder in jetty.base/webapps to be ROOT, so that works fine

**subdomain1.mydomain.org** - I have jetty.base/webapps/subdomain1.xml, so that also works

I want to serve two separate webapps at **subdomain2.mydomain.org** ie **subdomain2.mydomain.org/webapp1** and **subdomain2.mydomain.org/webapp2** which is where I'm stuck. I've tried to write xml files to point at the relevant folders and don't find any example of how to do this.

I can get both webapps responding simply by removing the xml files, but as well as responding at subdomain2.mydomain.org/webapp* they also appear at mydomain.org/webapp* which does not feel right. Surely it must be possible to limit the apps to the subdomain with xml files?

If it sounds like I'm being overly fussy, my reason for wanting this arrangement is to seamlessly replace an apache2/tomcat AJP setup with standalone jetty.

Various xml files have been tried, but I've not been able to get the arrangement I want. The problem seems to boil down to writing an xml file to place a webapp in a sub-folder of a virtualhost.